# Loading Facebook Javascript SDK Asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm attempting to load the all.js file asynchronously.

**In my ASCX file:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

**I've got a user control with an include of a javascript file:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
};

(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
```

However, when the page renders and loads, FB does not exist.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Sahil's answer is correct. By the time the document is rendered, there's no guarantee that any asynchronous scripts are already loaded.

If running your code from inside the `fbAsyncInit` callback is not what you want, you may consider two alternative approaches:

**Option 1**

Load the SDK synchronousy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

By doing so, `FB` will exist even before the document starts rendering.

**Option 2**

Check if the SDK has been already loaded and provide a fallback solution when not.

```
if (window.FB) {
    // use FB here ..
} else {
    // still loading, tell user to wait one more second
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That means the `FB` is called before it is initialized. Since it is initialized async, before the first time you use `FB` I would suggest you to write the `FB.init` code in you view instead of including it. Use like this-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
  });
  // use FB here ..
};
```